# Android - File Transfer Error while using Ejabberd and Smack

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack

I am using Smack 4.3.2 (Android client) and Ejabberd Server.
When I send a text it works very well. But I have a problem with File Transfer. 
When I’m trying send file I get this error.

I can get File info like `fileName` , `fileSize` but can’t get file. When I am sending from `=User1` to `=User2` I get the attached error.

But when I am sending from `=User1` to `=User1` it’s successful.

How can i fix that?

is anybody was have error like this? is any example with fileTransfer with ejabberd_18+smack4.3.2+android?

```
fileTransferManager.addFileTransferListener(
    new FileTransferListener() {
        @Override
        public void fileTransferRequest(final FileTransferRequest request) {
            IncomingFileTransfer transfer = request.accept();
            final File file = new File( “/storage/sdcard/Download/” + transfer.getFileName());
            try {
                transfer.receiveFile(file);
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
});
```

Here's the error:

```
myapplication1 W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$XMPPErrorException: XMPPError: item-not-found - cancel [Could not establish socket with any provided host]
05-04 21:54:21.190 9864-9924/com.example.myapplication1 W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.socks5.Socks5BytestreamRequest.cancelRequest(Socks5BytestreamRequest.java:289)
05-04 21:54:21.190 9864-9924/com.example.myapplication1 W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.socks5.Socks5BytestreamRequest.accept(Socks5BytestreamRequest.java:255)
05-04 21:54:21.190 9864-9924/com.example.myapplication1 W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.Socks5TransferNegotiator.negotiateIncomingStream(Socks5TransferNegotiator.java:102)
05-04 21:54:21.190 9864-9924/com.example.myapplication1 W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FaultTolerantNegotiator.createIncomingStream(FaultTolerantNegotiator.java:72)
05-04 21:54:21.190 9864-9924/com.example.myapplication1 W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer$2.call(IncomingFileTransfer.java:191)
05-04 21:54:21.190 9864-9924/com.example.myapplication1 W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer$2.call(IncomingFileTransfer.java:186)
05-04 21:54:21.190 9864-9924/com.example.myapplication1 W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-04 21:54:21.191 9864-9924/com.example.myapplication1 W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer.negotiateStream(IncomingFileTransfer.java:194)
05-04 21:54:21.192 9864-9924/com.example.myapplication1 W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer.access$100(IncomingFileTransfer.java:58)
05-04 21:54:21.192 9864-9924/com.example.myapplication1 W/System.err: at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.IncomingFileTransfer$1.run(IncomingFileTransfer.java:132)
05-04 21:54:21.192 9864-9924/com.example.myapplication1 W/System.err: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Make sure that both users can connect to each other and if they are behind NAT then use Socks5 proxy to facilitate the transfer.